# Event.ALT_MASK was deprecated

Tags: java, swing

Until a week ago I used Eclipse that had an internal Java 6 version
My old code for key driven menus in Java 6 for example was:

```
MenuItem mitem = new JMenuItem("blabla");
KeyStroke s44 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z,Event.ALT_MASK);
mitem.setAccelerator(s44);
```

After I got a new hard drive and restored all my programs and other data I saw, that
Eclipse now uses an internal Java 10 version
All my key driven actions did not work any longer, because „Event.ALT_MASK“ was deprecated.
After searching a lot for a replacement of „Event.ALT_MASK“ I tried

```
InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK
```

```
MenuItem mitem = new JMenuItem("blabla");
KeyStroke s44 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z,InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK);
mitem.setAccelerator(s44);
```

This is accepted by the compiler, but it does not work.

Can somebody tell me how I have to use KeyStroke to get a working accelerator key when I want to use the alt key?

Comment: `mitem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));`

Comment: Does `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("alt Z")` work?  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.String).

Comment: Sorry, both do not work.

Comment: It'll work just fine. Change the source [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/components-MenuDemoProject.zip) to have `VK_Z` instead of `VK_2` for the binding with `ActionEvent.ALT_MASK` and you'll find it works

Comment: this case is becoming more and more mysterious.
I use macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 and java: 10.0.2
I use: myMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
in my program.
There are 2 alt keys on the Mac keyboard, one to the left of the spacebar and cmd key and one to the right of the spacebar and cmd key.
If I press the left alt key and the Z key it works, even several times in a row. When I press the right alt key and Z key it doesn't work. My ActionListener then doesn't get an ActionEvent sent at all.

Comment: Now comes what I no longer understand at all:
I do 3 actions in a row
1. action: I press the left alt key and the Z key. It works.
2nd action: I press the right alt key and the Z key. It doesn't work.
3rd action: I press the left alt key and the Z key. It does not work anymore. My ActionListener then doesn't get an ActionEvent sent at all, no matter how often I repeat action. Only after exiting and restarting the program will the left alt key and the Z key work together again. Has anybody an idea what happens?

Comment: I can't say as I don't use a Mac. Linux has the utility `xev`that might diagnose what's coming from the hardware. That or the Mac equivalent could help

Comment: To verify that my Mac Keyboard is not damaged, I loaded the utility Key Codes form Apple store. I typed Alt Z using the right key alt and I typed Alt Z using the left key alt. Both deliver the same result.


Key Down
 Characters: Ω
 Unicode:  937 / 0x3a9
 Keys:  ⌥Z
 Key Code: 16 / 0x10
 Modifiers: 524608 / 0x80140 ⓘ

Key Down
 Characters: Ω
 Unicode:  937 / 0x3a9
 Keys:  ⌥Z
 Key Code: 16 / 0x10
 Modifiers: 524576 / 0x80120 ⓘ

Then I implemented a KeyListener to one of the components in my Java program and implemented some prints in the methods keyPressed

Comment: When I typed left alt key I got 
keyPressed keyCode: 18 keyChar: ?
ALT was pressed

When I typed right alt key I got 
keyPressed keyCode: 65406 keyChar: ? what is this????

Comment: For each 'Alt' key (afaicr they are normally called 'Option' keys in Apple), it might be worth doing `System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode()));` to see what you get

Comment: both deliver ⌥ . My solution will be to switch all shortcuts using alt key to shift shortcuts. Thanks so much.